# Video shortcode inside tabs shorcode NOT working

Tags: shortcode

I have the "video" shortcode and the "tabs" shortcode.

```
[video]code youtube[/video]

[tabs]
[tab title="text"][/tab]
[tab title="text"][/tab]
[/tabs]
```

If I write the video shortcode into a tab, the "video" shortcode doesn't work...
How can I resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to wrap content with `do_shortcode()`

I'm not sure what the exact function looks like, but for simplicity sake take a look at this example:

```
//[tab]Content[/tab]
function tab_func($atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    ), $atts ) );

    $output = '<div class="tab">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';

    return $output;
    }
add_shortcode( 'tab', 'tab_func' );
```

If you take a look at this line

`$output = '<div class="tab">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';`

you'll see that I am wrapping content inside the `do_shortcode` function which will execute any short code that WordPress finds inside content.

So in your case `[tab][video]youtube code[/video][/tab]` would now execute the YouTube code inside your tab.

Caveat: In my experience, this only works 1 level deep. If you have another level of short code you need to execute inside of the content, you'll need to make sure that those short code functions also include the `do_shortcode function`. i.e.:

```
[tab][video][title]Youtube code[/video][/tab]
```

In this example, `[title]` wouldn't display unless the `[video]` shortcode function also included do_shortcode.

Hope this helps. For more information, take a look at the WordPress documentation for `do_shortcode` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I used do_shortcode() in the tabs function and it works.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the code for the tabs shortcode to include:
    do_shortcode($content);